# Return after async function in Angular

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript

I'm writing project using Angular and RxJS. I implemented injectable class that retrieves data from JSON like this:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {Student} from './student.data';

@Injectable()
export class RosterService {
    private students : Student[];
    constructor(@Inject(Http) private http:Http){}

    private getStudents(){
        this.http.get('/JSON/students.json')
            .map(data => data.json().students)
            .subscribe(data => this.students = data);
    }

    public getRoster() {
        this.getStudents();
        return this.students;
    }
}
```

After I inject RosterService into constructor of AppComponent (including into @Component as provider):

```
export class AppComponent {
    public students : Student[];
    constructor(private _rosterService : RosterService) {
        this.students = _rosterService.getRoster();
    }
 }
```

But when I call getRoaster() method, it doesn't wait until getStudents (async get call) is executed. In the result I get undefined value.

How can I deal with it? Thanks for responce.

Comment: Extended my question. It isn't the same.

Comment: It's exactly the same. You've just added a couple of layers. You want `getRoster` to run `getStudents` synchronously (IOW, complete before returning `this.students`). The duplicate discusses how to structure your code to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use call back function, for example if it is a promise then i would use something like below.

```
var data;
asyncCall().then((result:any) => {
data = reuslt;
return data;
});
```

Not sure if that's what your looking for.

**Updated:**

```
        @Injectable()
    export class RosterService {
        private students : Student[];
        constructor(@Inject(Http) private http:Http){}

        private getStudents(){
            return this.http.get('/JSON/students.json')
                .map(data => data.json().students)
                .subscribe(data => this.students = data);
        }

        public getRoster() {
           return this.getStudents().then (() =>{
    return this.students;
           });        
         }
       }
```

And inside your AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent {
    public students : Student[];
    constructor(private _rosterService : RosterService) {
        this._rosterService.getRoster().then ((data:<T>)=>{
        this.students =data;
     });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I incorrectly expressed my question. Adjusted it.

Comment: Use the then on $http and return data in side it.

Comment: I don't know, is it correct in Javascript, but in Typescript you aren't allowed to return value inside asynchronous call

Comment: I have updated my answer, please look at it.

Comment: I found solution. You can return to the outer function not value, but promise, and subscribe to it in the outer function

Comment: But in any case these approaches make insignificant the whole dependency injection principle. :(

Comment: What do u mean these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've fundamentally missed a key design pattern in Javascript, which is the callback.

Instead of returning a value from the function, you pass in some code to execute when the function is good and ready.

```
function doSomething(success) {
    var data = 1;
    // blah blah blah, something happens.
    success(data);
}

function myFunction(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

doSomething(myFunction);
```

That way, you get to keep the asynchronous nature of the call, which doesn't block the single thread that Javascript has available.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I incorrectly expressed my question. Adjusted it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your asynchronous functions return promises.

---

First, the logic is kind of weird there.. `data` is scoped to the function, `func` can't access `data`.

Here's what you *probably* want to do:

```
function() {
  return func().then(data => data)
}
```

Except that makes that the same as this:

```
function() {
  return func()
}
```

..and in that case you might as well just replace that function with `func`!

```
func
```

(or if `func` is a property of some other object, `() => func()`.)

EDIT: This new function is an asynchronous function so of course it will return a promise. You'll need to use `.then` on it later to get the data from it.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, I incorrectly expressed my question. Adjusted it now. Thanks for your comment and scopes - I dropped it.